# Как устранить пиратский редирект с помощью htaccess?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Прошу помощи профессионалов. Случайно обнаружил в поиске свой сайт с пиратским редиректом от другого домена (идет полный копипаст моего сайта).

Попробуйте ввести в адресную строку `mmgp.ru.znakcomstva.ru` выдает редирект на мой сайт ёgame-topic.ruё на все мои страницы (дописав название страницы, к примеру, mmgp.ru.znakcomstva.ru/klanz.html и т.д.) в автоматическом режиме. Как только я загружаю новую страницу она появляется у него тоже.

Домен `mmgp.ru` приклеился и к другим чужим доменам. Проверял с 2 разных компьютеров и в разных браузерах. В robots.txt Host указан, в яндекс.вебмастере тоже. На одном из форумов мне ответили что можно с помощью htaccess выставить редирект на 1 домен со всех иных адресов, по которым находят сайт. Что нужно прописать в .htaccess для редиректа на свой домен со всех иных адресов использующих мой сайт.

Comment: А я что-то не вижу никакого пиратства. Все URL на сайте mmgp.ru.znakcomstva.ru выдают 301 на соответствующие URL на game-topic.ru. Как будто там тупо `Redirect` в `.htaccess`. О чём вообще тогда речь?

Comment: См. выше проблему решил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, нашел лучшее решение подсказали на другом форуме прописал

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^game-topic\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://game-topic.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Все страницы с чужого url которые используют мой домен теперь ведут на мой сайт. Кто-то сделал доменное зеркало.

Comment: Какую проблему, в чём она? От того, что где-то настроили редирект на ваш сайт, вам ни жарко, ни холодно. И ваши правила в `.htaccess` вообще ни на что не влияют (точнее, влияют, но к данному случаю это никакого отношения не имеет).

Comment: Это был не редирект а доменное зеркало. В последнее время я заметил необоснованно много отказов по яндекс метрике и переходов на мой сайт сайтов конкурентов, плюс выросло число посетителей с закладок и с "не веб страница" и при этом в разы увеличилось количество отказов, т.е. посетитель находился на сайте менее 15 сек и перехода на другую страницу, посетитель с поиска идет а толку нет, чего раньше не было, думаю что это связанно именно с этим. Все эти факторы влияют на ПФ. Пока ничего сказать не могу посмотрим что будет дальше. Я рад что нашел решение по возникшей проблеме!

Comment: Вот только проверка `HTTP_HOST` в этой ситуации вам не даёт ровным счётом вообще ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы просто добавил скрипт, который проверял бы текущий урл, и если от не принадлежит Вашему сайту, то делать редирект (это две строки кода).

```
if (document.location.origin != 'http://mmgp.ru.znakcomstva.ru') { document.location = "http://mmgp.ru";}
```

(этот код будет редиректить на главную, но можно доделать, что бы редиректило на нужные страницы)

И я бы рекомендовал убрать код, который блокирует правую кнопку мыши. Это наивно.